# how to replace existed (specific) fragment with another fragment in the same position in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

if i have three fragments and i need to replace specific one by another how can i do this ? and how does replace method work in fragment transaction ? i find it replace one fragment by another if i have one fragment visible but if i have two fragments visible it replace a random one and if i have 4 fragments it replace two fragments by one!
in this program below i tried to add 4 fragments by using (add A) and (add B) Buttons but the problem exists when i try to use (replace A with B) or (replace B with A) buttons this will replace random fragment by fragment A or B.

***Main Activity***

```
package com.example.muhammad_adel.transaction;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FragmentManager manager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    manager = getFragmentManager();
}

public void addA(View view) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    transaction.add(R.id.linearLayout, fragmentA, "addA");
    transaction.commit();
}

public void removeA(View view) {
    FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentByTag("addA");
    if (fragmentA != null && fragmentA.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(fragmentA);
        transaction.commit();

    }
}

public void replaceAwithB(View view) {
    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.linearLayout, fragmentB, "addB");
    transaction.commit();
}

public void addB(View view) {
    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.linearLayout, fragmentB, "addB");
    transaction.commit();
}

public void removeB(View view) {

    FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentByTag("addB");
    if (fragmentB != null && fragmentB.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove(fragmentB);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public void replaceBwithA(View view) {
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.linearLayout, fragmentA, "addA");

    transaction.commit();

}

public void attachA(View view) {
    FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentByTag("addA");
    if (fragmentA != null && !fragmentA.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.attach(fragmentA);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public void attachB(View view) {
    FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentByTag("addB");
    if (fragmentB != null && !fragmentB.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.attach(fragmentB);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public void DetachedA(View view) {

    FragmentA fragmentA = (FragmentA) manager.findFragmentByTag("addA");
    if (fragmentA != null && fragmentA.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.detach(fragmentA);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public void DetachedB(View view) {
    FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentByTag("addB");
    if (fragmentB != null && fragmentB.isVisible()) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.detach(fragmentB);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}}
public void replaceAOnlyWithB(View view) {

}
```

**FragmentA**

```
package com.example.muhammad_adel.transaction;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}
```

**FragmentB**

```
package com.example.muhammad_adel.transaction;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.muhammad_adel.transaction.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add A"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="addA"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remove A"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="removeA"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Replace A with B"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:onClick="replaceAwithB"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Attach A"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="attachA"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add B"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="addB"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remove B"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="removeB"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Replace B with A"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="replaceBwithA"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Attach B"
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="attachB"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Replace A Only with B"
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button4"
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:text="Detached A"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="DetachedA"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button11"
        android:layout_below="@id/button8"
        android:text="Detached B"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:onClick="DetachedB"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button11"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3498db"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hello Man this is Fragment A"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_b.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F92"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Hello man this is Fragment B"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the fragment with the following way 
step 1: Set the id of the layout you want to replace with the other fragment.

**fragment xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.neelay.level47.Fragment.Album"
android:background="#4d263238"
android:id="@+id/replace_frag">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

Step 2: Set the onclick in your fragment and just do the fragment transaction

**Fragment java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_album, container, false);

    Button button =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Fragment someFragment = new Replacement();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.replace_frag, someFragment ); // give your fragment container id in first parameter
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);  // if written, this transaction will be added to backstack
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

I am replacing the fragment in a scrollable tab and if you want to replace all the scrollable tab then you can set the id of your content_main

Comment: sorry for saying this, you don't understand my question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried what you say, but this does not answer my question. Thanks again for trying.

Comment: Let me try I will let you know

Comment: okay, let me divides my question into two questions. First one: assume that there are 5 fragments and a button in tablet screen then if the user click in the button this will replace fragment number 3 and put another fragment in the same position of old fragment not in a random position. how can i do this ? if you give me answer for this question this may help solve the other questions.

Comment: you mean you want to replace one of the fragment of the scrollable tab when button clicked?

Comment: yes, but replace specific fragment and but another one in the same position of old one. let me say that i have fragmentA, fragmentB and fragementC and i want to replace fragmentB by fragementD. i know that i can use remove method to remove fragmentB then use add method to add fragmentD but this doesn't put the fragmentD in the same position of fragmentB.

Comment: see the up date ans

Comment: but in this way you can not use getItemPosition it will refresh you your fragment and you will get the old fragment this is happening in infinite scrollview

Comment: sorry for late respond. I tried to do what you said in my main project which i but it's code above. and i tried to handle the button which called (ReplaceAOnlayWithB) and it gives me a  **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException** when i click on it. create a new project and drag and drop my code and try to run it this will make things clear.